# Cannot configure phpmyadmin vhost

Tags: php, apache-2.4, phpmyadmin

With Apache 2.4, PHP7 & Phpmyadmin on a Windows Server 2016 VM: unable to properly configure phpmyadmin to be accessible as path from site.  Site is a Symfony application that throws a 404 when `site/phpmyadmin` is requested.

`mod_alias` is loaded

httpd-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName admin.projectmana.org
    ServerAlias projectmana.org
    DocumentRoot "c:\apache24\htdocs\projectmana\htdocs"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin projectmana.app@gmail.com
    ServerName admin.projectmana.org
    Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/Apache24/htdocs/phpmyadmin"
    <Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs/phpmyadmin">
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

#### Edit

Result of httpd -S (after `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`)

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server admin.projectmana.org (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:24)
         port 80 namevhost admin.projectmana.org (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:24)
                 alias projectmana.org
         port 80 namevhost admin.projectmana.org (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:30)
ServerRoot: "C:/Apache24"
Main DocumentRoot: "C:/Apache24/htdocs/projectMana/htdocs"
Main ErrorLog: "C:/Apache24/logs/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="C:/Apache24/logs/" mechanism=default
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "C:/Apache24/logs/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help from this [Ubuntu forums answer](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1629708), I made the following the sole entry in `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName admin.projectmana.org
    ServerAlias projectmana.org
    DocumentRoot "c:\apache24\htdocs\projectMana\htdocs"
    Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/Apache24/htdocs/phpmyadmin"
    <Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs/phpmyadmin">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```